# excel VBA match 2 cell on different sheets if match then delete sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have sheet with name LIST, and in cell K15 is some value. What i need is for macro to check all other sheets and if it match value from (LIST) - (K15)  to cell (B4) on all other sheets in workbook, and it will be always that place (B4). If it get match then delete that sheet.

So it is some kind of match loop macro.

Please help me

```
Sub DeleteSheets01()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   If Worksheets("LIST").Range("K15") = LenB(ActiveSheet.Range("B4")) Then ActiveSheet.Delete
 Next ws
 End Sub
```

Comment: I have searched forums and got stuck on this small thing so i need help to finish my macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it

```
Sub DeleteSheets01()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   If ws.Range("B4") = Worksheets("LIST").Range("K15") Then
       ws.Delete
   End If
  Next ws
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```